# Base 64 PDF blocked - reason reflected-xss block?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, get, xss, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to show a base64 pdf that I get through a GET request but for some reason it gets blocked in Chrome for the following reason or at least I think it gets blocked because of this since I see an error in the console stating the following:

```
Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'reflected-xss'.
```

When I check my logs, I see that the pdf is correctly formatted in base64 because decrypting it results in the PDF, but Chrome just doesn't want to open it

In the response header I do see the following:

```
Content-Security-Policy:reflected-xss block
Content-Type:application/pdf
```

however, I'm not too familiar with this so any idea how I go about this to make this work? Or can anyone at least tell me why I'm getting that?

I do notice that when I try another pdf it works but that the response header for the one that works has Connection:keep-alive?

Comment: As far as the context for that error message, see the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107485/unrecognized-content-security-policy-directive-reflected-xss-error-related-t/42515546#42515546 and https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=657737. The 'reflected-xss' CSP directive was in some earlier drafts of the W3C Content Security Policy spec and support for it was implemented at one point in Chrome but subsequently removed. As far as what to do about, if you don’t control the server that’s sending the PDF with that Content-Security-Policy, there’s nothing you can do

Comment: "decoding", not "decrypting". Base64 is not encryption.

Comment: Are the response headers the same for working pdfs and this one (except connection: keep-alive) ?

Comment: Issue is found, the way I created the header to send the pdf to the front end 
was badly formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entering my own answer to this question so that it has an official one (after all this time):
As per my comment, the root cause was the way I created the header to send the pdf to the front end was badly formed. It got blocked by my company's F5 firewall.